# Setting up flat rate + per seat product in Stripe/Firebase

Tags: firebase, next.js, stripe-payments

How would I create a product in Stripe that has a flat rate plus a per seat fee?
For example, $99 a month plus $9/member.

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can take a look at this section in Stripe's documentation : https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#flat-rate-per-seat

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.